# Consecutive coin flips across n trials.

Tags: statistics

I did a little research on stack exchange, and found this question that was very similar to my own. However, my education is only that of a freshman in 
highschool, and I was unable to understand a large majority of their work.

[Probability of a winning consecutive $k$-subset out of $n$ coin flips](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446986/probability-of-a-winning-consecutive-k-subset-out-of-n-coin-flips)

My question is as follows:
You have a weighted coin, 30% chance to fall on tails, and 70% to fall on heads. What is the chance across *n* coin flips that the coin lands upon heads *x* times in a row.

I ask that the answer to this question be explained as simply as possible, or for help to implement this in google sheets.

Comment: Exactly or at least?  Suppose you're looking for exactly 3 in a row out of five. Write down the possibilities and their respective probabilities. Maybe that will give you an idea how to generalize: `SSSFF FSSSF FFSSS`

Comment: I would do this, except I'm looking at combinations that are way too big for my computer to handle, let alone by hand

Comment: You should do it anyhow, unless you have a satisfactory answer by now. Once you see how it works for small $n$ and $k$ you should be able to write a general formula.